# Remove CDATA from Joomla RSS

Tags: joomla, rss

My Joomla RSS-feed gives by the description-tag this:

```
<![CDATA[<div class="feed-description"><p> ... </p></div>]]>
```

How can I remove that so only my text from my article show?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the renderer to decide what to show. If you don't want to have data there leave the description of the category empty.

Comment: You are right Elin, but I think Rick wants to get rid of the HTML tags leaving plain text. Rick consider using strip_tags

Comment: But the description is not the text of the article, it is the description of the feed as a whole.

Comment: Here's the link of the feed: http://www.abcouderfeestweek.nl/index.php/nieuws?format=feed&type=rss

Comment: http://tags.cloudaccess.net/using-joomla/extensions/components.feed   WHat version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Joomla 3.0.3, the newest. And also in your link i'll see <![CDATA[ by the description

Comment: 3.1.1 is the newest and what you should be on if you are using J3. Do you see how my feed has the article text in the place for actual articles? RSS Feeds have very well defined published standards and that is how they should look.